# Haskell - How to create a matrix

Tags: list, haskell, matrix

Given the size of an matrix and a position p. How do I fill the matrix with 1 in p and 0 in other positions?

```
Ex.: size=(3,3) p=(3,1)

[0 0 0]
[0 0 0]
[1 0 0]
```

I defined:

```
type Matrix= [[Int]]
type Pos = (Int,Int)

f:: Pos->Pos->Matrix
```

The `f` return for example would be:

```
 [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[1,0,0]]
```

I'm having trouble to start, i.e. in idea how to implement the function `f`. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I like AndrewC's answer, but I'd do it in one go, nesting the list comprehensions and just testing equality for positions, rather than separate rows and columns.

```
f :: Pos -> Pos -> Matrix
f (h, w) p =  [ [if (y, x) == p then 1 else 0 | x <- [1..w]]
              | y <- [1..h]]
```

I've chosen my alignment mnemonically so that `x` stretches horizontally and `y` stretches vertically, with the heart of the thing being the expression that defines a typical element in terms of its coordinates. The comparison on columns won't happen if the rows are different. I suppose one could use `replicate w 0` to compute the all-zero rows slightly more efficiently, at a cost of clarity.

I'd also consider writing

```
g :: Pos -> Pos -> Matrix
g (h, w) (y, x)  =   replicate (y-1) wzeros
                 ++  (replicate (x-1) 0 ++ 1 : replicate (w-x) 0)
                 :   replicate (h-y) wzeros
  where wzeros = replicate w 0
```

which is longer, but even more spatially immediate. It preserves more sharing and perhaps does a little less subtraction. But its behaviour is a bit weirder if the position is outside the relevant range.

Comment: I'd nest the comprehensions myself too, but since May is doing a series of Haskell assignments, I chose a couple of conceptual stepping stones and left some gaps. Maybe there's a slick solution to the [current question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877756/haskell-manipulating-lists) too.

Answer (score 5):

You could do it by two list comprehensions, one used inside each other:

Break the problem down into two smaller but similar problems:

```
row b lengthacross = 
   [ --some expression that's 1 if x == b and zero otherwise
         | x <- [1..lengthacross]]
```

What type would `row` have?

```
matrix (a,b) (lendown,lenacross) = 
   [ --a row with a 1 in it or just zeros as appropriate 
        | y <- --an appropriate list
          ]
```

What type would `matrix` have?

Answer (score 3):

Decompose it.

1. Write a function of type `Pos -> [[Pos]]` that takes a size, and gives a "matrix" of that size, but with each element being its own position.

   e.g. `ofSize (2,2) = [[(1,1), (1,2)], [(2,1), (2,2)]]`
2. Write a function of type `(a -> b) -> [[a]] -> [[b]]` that works similarly to `map`. (Clue: the definition features `map`. Twice.)

You can then assemble these pieces into a function that starts by generating a "matrix" of positions, then maps that into the desired result.