# Manipulating lists of lists

Tags: list, haskell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Haskell - Manipulating lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877756/haskell-manipulating-lists)

Given a matrix `m`,a starting position `p1` and a final point `p2`. 
The objective is to compute how many ways there are to reach the final matrix (p2=1 and others=0). For this, every time you skip into a position you decrements by one.
 you can only skip from one position to another by at most two positions, horizontal or vertical. For example:

```
   m =             p1=(3,1)  p2=(2,3)
   [0 0 0]
   [1 0 4]
   [2 0 4]
```

You can skip to the positions `[(3,3),(2,1)]`

When you skip from one position you decrement it by one and does it all again. Let's skip to the first element of the list. Like this:

```
    m=              
    [0 0 0]
    [1 0 4]
    [1 0 4]
```

Now you are in position `(3,3)` and you can skip to the positions `[(3,1),(2,3)]`

And doing it until the final matrix:

```
[0 0 0]
[0 0 0]
[1 0 0]
```

In this case the amount of different ways to get the final matrix is `20`.
I've created the functions below:

```
import Data.List
type Pos = (Int,Int)
type Matrix = [[Int]]

s::Pos->Pos->Matrix->Int
s (i,j) fim mat = if (mat == (matrizFinal (tamanho mat) fim)) then 1 
                else if (possiveisMov (i,j) mat)/= [] then s (head(possiveisMov (i,j) mat)) fim (decrementaPosicao (i,j) mat)
                 else 0



matrizFinal:: Pos->Pos->Matrix
matrizFinal (m,n) p = [[if (y,x)==p then 1 else 0 | x<-[1..n]]| y<-[1..m]]

movimentos::Pos->[Pos]
movimentos (i,j)= [(i+1,j),(i+2,j),(i-1,j),(i-2,j),(i,j+1),(i,j+2),(i,j-1),(i,j-2)]

decrementaPosicao:: Pos->Matrix->Matrix
decrementaPosicao (1,c) (m:ms) = (decrementa c m):ms
decrementaPosicao (l,c) (m:ms) = m:(decrementaPosicao (l-1,c) ms)

decrementa:: Int->[Int]->[Int]
decrementa 1 (m:ms) = (m-1):ms
decrementa n (m:ms) = m:(decrementa (n-1) ms)

tamanho:: Matrix->Pos
tamanho m = (length m,length.head $ m)

possiveisMov:: Pos->Matrix->[Pos]
possiveisMov p mat = verifica0 ([(a,b)|a<-(dim m),b<-(dim n)]  `intersect` xs) mat
                          where xs = movimentos p
                            (m,n) = tamanho mat
dim:: Int->[Int]
dim 1 = [1]
dim n = n:dim (n-1)

verifica0::[Pos]->Matrix->[Pos]
verifica0 [] m =[]
verifica0 (p:ps) m = if ((pegaAltura m p) == 0) then verifica0 ps m
                                               else p:verifica0 ps m

pegaAltura:: Matrix->Pos->Int
pegaAltura x (i,j)= (x!!(i-1))!!(j-1)
```

Does anyone know why the function `s` doesn't count how many ways to solve this problem? how do I fix it or a better way to make the function `s` that solves?

Answer (score 0):

After I recognized that the game being played was multiple token marbles, I knew that to count the number of paths from a start to an end is done by expanding game tree and if the board found is the end board then count that as a path other wise don't.

So I then saw that your `s` function only expands the board in one way *the first possible move* rather than in all possible moves. The correct version would test if the board is in the end state and return 1 and otherwise sum up the results from a loop over all of the possible moves resulting in a count or 0 if that move is not valid.